# Xcode 7, no way to test touch id with simulator with iPad Air 2 ?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

There doesn't seem to be any way to test the touch id on supporting iPads in the simulator.

iPad Air 2 and some others support touch id.

My app is iPad only and I don't own an iPad with touch id, but the options in the simulator are greyed out.

Am I missing something ?

My app is iPad only and I don't have a newer iPad.

[image]

Comment: No, it seems that they haven't updated the iPad Air 2 simulator. You can log a bug with Apple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, this is a bug that nobody noticed before shipping.  Please file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com

You can work around this yourself by just editing the profile.plist inside of the iPad Air 2.simdevicetype bundle, but doing so will invalidate Xcode.app's signature which will break delta updates from the store (you'd have to download the entire Xcode.app rather than just the changes).